# Voobly Rating points

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I'm playing Age of Empires 2: The Conquerors at [Voobly](http://www.voobly.com/home) but neither I receive Rating points nor "Win" or "Loss" points.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Are you playing Rated games? To receive points you need to have ratings enabled.

The rating system doesn't record games if anti-cheat is not enabled.